# How to get the collections inside a document in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all the collections inside the document, but i am getting errors.

I am doing this:

```
this.db = firebase.firestore();

this.db.collection("RestaurantMenus").doc(this.restaurant.key).listCollections().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((collection) => {
        console.log("collection: " + collection.id);
      });
```

And it says listCollections() is not a function. I tried getAllCollections() its says the same. I tried to get the data from the doc but in only get the data and not the collections.

I dont know what else to do.What i am doing wrong?

My firestore:

Collection --- > "RestaurantMenus" ----> doc: this.restaurant.key ----> collection that i want to get

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you're trying to call are only available in the server-side SDKs for Firestore. There is no API to get a list of collections using the **client** SDKs for Firestore.

For this reason you'll typically want to use fixed names (like your "RestaurantMenus") for your collection ID, and only use generated IDs for documents.